# Troubles with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just started to learn react, and i have a question
Well, i can impact on state from one component to another. But can i do it in reverse?

Here's what i mean:

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import Butt from './Button';

    class Checkbox extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super();
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Butt arg={13} />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default Checkbox;
```

```js
    import React from 'react';

    class Butt extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super();
            this.state = {
                s1: props.arg,
            };
        }

        add = () => {
            let val = this.state.s1;
            val++;
            this.setState({ s1: val });
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <label>
                            <button onClick={this.add}>add</button>
                            <div>{this.state.s1}</div>
                        </label>
                    </label>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default Butt;
```

Sorry for my silly question. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  What exactly isn't working as expected in your code?

Comment: What do you mean about doing it reverse? Do you mean [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question, but in react, there is a one-way flow (from parent to child) for transferring information (props, states, or ...). If you want to have access to states everywhere or set them in each direction you should use `Redux` or `context` or any other state management.

Answer (score 0):

You're updating the `Butt` state from inside `Butt` so this will work fine. It won't change the value of `this.props.arg` though, if that's what you're asking.

Props are always non-mutable.

What you can do is have two components share the state of their parent...

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    val = 0
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <>
        <Child1 
         val={this.state.val} 
         onChange={newVal => this.setState({ val: newVal })} 
        />
        <Child2 
          val={this.state.val} 
          onChange={newVal => this.setState({ val: newVal })} 
        />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Then inside the child components pass the updated value to `onChange`...

```js
class Child1 extends React.Component {
  handleChange() {
    this.props.onChange(this.props.val + 1)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button onClick={() => this.handleChange()}>
        Update value
      </Button>
    )
  }
}
```

This way you're just passing a new value from `Child` to `Parent` and letting `Parent` decide what to do with it.

Whether `Child1` or `Child2` sends the new value, both children will get updated when `Parent` calls `this.setState({ val: newVal })` and changes `this.state.val`.